# Reflection library - call to RunStaticMethod returns error

Tags: basic4android

i am trying to call the MotionEvent.obtain Methode using the reflections library.
But so far i am not very successful. Everything i try results in the same error...
Here my code from a button-click:

```
Dim upTime As Long
Dim ev As Object
Dim args(12) As Object
Dim types(12) As String

upTime = Obj1.RunStaticMethod("android.os.SystemClock", "uptimeMillis", Null, Null)

'public static MotionEvent obtain (Long downTime, Long eventTime, Int action, Float x, Float y, Float pressure, Float size, Int metaState, Float xPrecision, Float yPrecision, Int deviceId, Int edgeFlags)
'Since: API Level 1
'Create a new MotionEvent, filling in all of the basic values that define the motion.
'Parameters:
'downTime   The time (in ms) when the user originally pressed down To start a stream of position events. This must be obtained from uptimeMillis().
args(0) = upTime
types(0) = "java.lang.long"
'eventTime  The the time (in ms) when this specific event was generated. This must be obtained from uptimeMillis().
args(1) = upTime
types(1) = "java.lang.long"
'action The kind of action being performed, such As ACTION_DOWN.
args(2) = "1" 'MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
types(2) = "java.lang.int"
'x  The X coordinate of this event.
args(3) = "50.0"
types(3) = "java.lang.float"
'y  The Y coordinate of this event.
args(4) = "20.0"
types(4) = "java.lang.float"
'pressure   The current pressure of this event. The pressure generally ranges from 0 (no pressure at all) To 1 (normal pressure), however values higher than 1 may be generated depending on the calibration of the input device.
args(5) = "1.0"
types(5) = "java.lang.float"
'size   A scaled value of the approximate size of the area being pressed when touched with the finger. The actual value in pixels corresponding To the finger touch Is normalized with a device specific range of values AND scaled To a value between 0 AND 1.
args(6) = "1.0"
types(6) = "java.lang.float"
'metaState  The state of any meta / modifier keys that were in effect when the event was generated.
args(7) = "0"
types(7) = "java.lang.int"
'xPrecision The precision of the X coordinate being reported.
args(8) = "1.0"
types(8) = "java.lang.float"
'yPrecision The precision of the Y coordinate being reported.
args(9) = "1.0"
types(9) = "java.lang.float"
'deviceId   The id For the device that this event came from. An id of zero indicates that the event didn't come from a physical device; other numbers are arbitrary and you shouldn't depend on the values.
args(10) = "0"
types(10) = "java.lang.int"
'edgeFlags  A bitfield indicating which edges, If any, were touched by this MotionEvent.
args(11) = "0"
types(11) = "java.lang.int"
'call methode
***ev = Obj2.RunStaticMethod("android.view.MotionEvent", "obtain", args, types)***
```

> Here the error occurs (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch):

```
10-09 09:02:26.951: ERROR/B4A(296): ev = Obj2.RunStaticMethod("android.view.MotionEvent", "obtain", args, types)
```

10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at anywheresoftware.b4a.agraham.reflection.Reflection.RunStaticMethod(Reflection.java:860)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at anywheresoftware.b4a.agraham.reflectiondemo.main._button2_click(main.java:564)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at anywheresoftware.b4a.BA.raiseEvent2(BA.java:105)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at anywheresoftware.b4a.BA.raiseEvent2(BA.java:93)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at anywheresoftware.b4a.BA.raiseEvent(BA.java:89)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at anywheresoftware.b4a.objects.ViewWrapper$1.onClick(ViewWrapper.java:49)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 09:02:26.961: ERROR/B4A(296): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

```
Dim args1(1) As Object
Dim types1(1) As String
args1(0) = ev
types1(0) = "android.view.MotionEvent"

Obj2.Target = Activity
Obj2.RunStaticMethod("android.view.View","dispatchTouchEvent",args1,types1)
```

Any help would be great...
Thank you,
Richard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see the  [Multitouch tutorial?](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/showthread.php?p=57977) Maybe the Gestures library already does what you need.

Anyway you can do it with this code:

```
Sub Activity_Create(FirstTime As Boolean)
    Dim me As Object
    me = ObtainMotionEvent(1000, 1000, 1, 100, 100, 500, 500, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0)
    Log(me)
End Sub


Sub ObtainMotionEvent(DownTime As Long, EventTime As Long, Action As Int, _
    X As Float, Y As Float, Pressure As Float, Size As Float, MetaState As Int, _
    XPrecision As Float, YPrecision As Float, DeviceId As Int, EdgeFlags As Int) As Object
    Dim r As Reflector
    Dim f, i As String
    f = "java.lang.float"
    i = "java.lang.int"
    l = "java.lang.long"
    Return r.RunStaticMethod("android.view.MotionEvent", "obtain", _
        Array As Object(DownTime, EventTime, Action, X, Y, Pressure, Size, MetaState, _
            XPrecision, YPrecision, DeviceId, EdgeFlags), _
        Array As String(l, l, i, f, f, f, f, i, f, f, i, i))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer you provided.
This works, but was is the difference to my call?

Comment: You are passing strings instead of numbers: args(6) = "1.0" this should be: args(6) = 1

Comment: I have also seen the gestures library, but it does not help.
My problem i want to solve is that a user should be able to scroll the  page (leftToright) if he starts with the gesture on any view (edit field). But now if he do so the view (for example a edit field) is activated and the move action does not occur.